# Integer.parseInt() keeps making a string equal to 1

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText startTime, taking in user input. The user will enter a time, for example(7:35).

I get the string inputted and then I split the string:

```
String startTimeString = startTime.getText().toString();
String [] eventStartTime = startTimeString.split(Pattern.quote(":"));
```

I then cast these values into Integers:

```
int startHour = Integer.parseInt(eventStartTime[0]);
int startMinute = Integer.parseInt(eventStartTime[1]);
```

Given the input example that I provided, I expect eventStartTime[0] to contain the integer 7 and eventStartTime[1] to contain the integer 35.

But when I display these values using a Toast, startHour is 7 as expected but startMinute is 1 which is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: Simply use `String [] eventStartTime = startTimeString.split(":");`

Comment: Print out `startTimeString`. Maybe your `startTime` object is returning something unusual.

Comment: are you sure you need the Pattern.quote? shouldn't split(":") be sufficient?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it: http://ideone.com/wUSw2D. Prints 7 35 7 35. Are you sure your input has the proper format?